# Green dot inside the viewfinder always blinks in manual mode in my D5200. Is this normal?

Tags: manual-mode

i just bought Nikon D5200 2 weeks ago. I have started experimenting with that. Put it in manual mode M and try to take a shot of some scene. But the green dot inside the viewfinder blinks and does not go still. Is this normal? Would the green dot should go still or what? please clarify.

Thanks, 
Baskaran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the green dot on the left hand side, it is the focus indicator.  It is possible you are using an aperture that is too small for the camera to provide focus confirmation or that the camera is unable to achieve focus for some other reason.  More detail is available on page 22, 36 and 40 in your manual.

Comment: Thanks Henderson. Yes, exactly it is focus indicator. sorry i didnt know the exact wording "focus indicator" to mention. i would read the manual and get back to you if the issue still persists. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

That green dot is your focus aid.  It comes on steady when you are in focus -it's to help you focus manually.

In the old days when cameras were all manual focus, the viewfinder had a "split image" center or a "grain magnifier" in the center to help with focusing. Modern auto-focus cameras don't have that aid, so, unless you have good eyes, you find that it's quite tough to get a good focus manually. Also lenses don't help - focus ring is narrow and the roation is less then 60 deg from end to end rather than 270 degs in the old days.

So, the green dot tells you that you are in focus.  In my D7100, there's an option to turn it off - don't know if you have that in the D5200 - look your your menu settings under shooting and focus submenu.